# Google Geocoding API - return any valid address based of zip code

Tags: api, geocoding

I need to return any (at least one) valid address that exist around a zip code.
The country will always be the same.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this through 2 requests, using the output of the first as input for the second. There are a few caveats outlined at the end.

**Request 1**
Get data based on Zip Code:

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=90058&key={{YOUR_API_KEY}}'
```

From your response you will want to take `results[0].geometry.location` object. You will use the `lat` and `lng` values for your next query. The example above provides the following:

```js
   // … more above
        "formatted_address" : "Los Angeles, CA 90058, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.045639,
                  "lng" : -118.1685449
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.979672,
                  "lng" : -118.2435201
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 34.00637469999999,
               "lng" : -118.2234229
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.045639,
                  "lng" : -118.1685449
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.979672,
                  "lng" : -118.2435201
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJDeH8s8TIwoARYQFWkBcCzFk",

   // … more below
```

**Request 2**
Get data based on Latitude and Longitude

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.00637469999999,-118.2234229&key={{YOUR_API_KEY}}'
```

**NOTE! The query param has changed from `address` to `latlng`**

This will likely return many results, you will have to decide which type meets your requirements, but I would recommend looping through the results array and looking for an entry with a `types` array which includes `street_address` or `premise` and using that entry as your target result set.

For the example above, `results[1]` will have `"types" : [ "premise" ]` 
Its associated `formatted_address` and the complete parent object will be as follows:

- *see note at bottom on targeting specific types*

```
"formatted_address" : "2727 E Vernon Ave, Vernon, CA 90058, USA",
```

```js
   // … more above
      {
         "address_components": [
            {
               "long_name": "2727",
               "short_name": "2727",
               "types": [
                  "street_number"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "East Vernon Avenue",
               "short_name": "E Vernon Ave",
               "types": [
                  "route"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "Vernon",
               "short_name": "Vernon",
               "types": [
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "Los Angeles County",
               "short_name": "Los Angeles County",
               "types": [
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "California",
               "short_name": "CA",
               "types": [
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "United States",
               "short_name": "US",
               "types": [
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "90058",
               "short_name": "90058",
               "types": [
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "1822",
               "short_name": "1822",
               "types": [
                  "postal_code_suffix"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address": "2727 E Vernon Ave, Vernon, CA 90058, USA",
         "geometry": {
            "bounds": {
               "northeast": {
                  "lat": 34.0065676,
                  "lng": -118.2228652
               },
               "southwest": {
                  "lat": 34.0057081,
                  "lng": -118.2245065
               }
            },
            "location": {
               "lat": 34.0061691,
               "lng": -118.2236056
            },
            "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport": {
               "northeast": {
                  "lat": 34.0074868302915,
                  "lng": -118.2223368697085
               },
               "southwest": {
                  "lat": 34.0047888697085,
                  "lng": -118.2250348302915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id": "ChIJCQv2_sPIwoARZn8W2bF9a9g",
         "types": [
            "premise"
         ]
      },

   // … more below
```

**Caveats**

- I assume since you said "Zip Code" you meant the United States. I only tested for the US, if you need other country support, consider adding the country code to your address query params in request 1.
- If you use this approach starting with Zip Code, you might encounter results with a `route` or `street_address` but no `premise` if the Zip Code represents a large geographic area with a very low population density. I tested this on "Vernon, California (90058) - population 112" and "Freeport City, Kansas (67049) - population 5". Freeport City returned no result having type of `premise`.
- If you want to query a specific type so you don't have to search through a large result set, you can apply the query param `&result_type=premise` to request 2. However, if no result exists for the given lat/lng with your specified type(s), you will receive a `results.status` = `ZERO_RESULTS`.
- Multiple `result_type` values may be applied, separate with a pipe (`|`)
- Full docs here on Reverse Geocoding: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding